# Different CSS transition-delays for hover and mouseout for a span element in a div?

Tags: html, css

I've seen examples online of using the :hover pseudo-class to simulate a mouseover/mouseout effect in CSS3... I would like for a child element to appear when its parent element is hovered over, but I would like for the child element to disappear with a different delay on mouseout (my text currently eases in and out slowly, but I would prefer for it to fade quickly on ease-out). The way my code is set up, the :hover pseudo element doesn't naturally lend itself to this effect... Any thoughts?

```css
div {
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition-delay
}
section {
  display: table; margin: 0 auto;
}
.boots {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.laugh {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.awesome {
  width: 54px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.happy {
  width: 52px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}
div > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0.5s;
}

.boots:hover {
  width: 170px; 
}
.laugh:hover {
  width: 190px;
}
.awesome:hover {
  width: 290px;
}
.happy:hover {
  width: 195px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class = "boots">B<span>oots</span></div>
  <div class = "laugh">L<span>augh</span></div>
  <div class = "awesome">A<span>wesome</span></div>
  <div class = "happy">H<span>appy</span></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is pretty easy just set the transition delay to 0s in normal state `div > span` (means when your transition return from hover state to normal state the delay should be 0 which will make the text disappear quicker)

**Note:** I have added a transition delay property to `div > span` and its value is `0s` and it is the key to fade the text quicker when you mouse out

```css
    div {
      font-size: 72px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      transition-delay
    }
    section {
      display: table; margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .boots {
      width: 50px;
      background-color: grey;
      transition: width 1s;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .laugh {
      width: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      transition: width 1s;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .awesome {
      width: 54px;
      background-color: orange;
      transition: width 1s;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .happy {
      width: 52px;
      background-color: green;
      transition: width 1s;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    div > span {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline;
      visibility:hidden;
      opacity:0;
      transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
      transition-delay:0s;
    }
    div:hover > span {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline;
      visibility:visible;
      opacity:1;
      transition-delay:0.5s;
    }

    .boots:hover {
      width: 170px; 
    }
    .laugh:hover {
      width: 190px;
    }
    .awesome:hover {
      width: 290px;
    }
    .happy:hover {
      width: 195px;
    }
```

```html
 <section>
      <div class = "boots">B<span>oots</span></div>
      <div class = "laugh">L<span>augh</span></div>
      <div class = "awesome">A<span>wesome</span></div>
      <div class = "happy">H<span>appy</span></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but you aren't going to get many upvotes unless you explain what you did, why you did it, and how it works.

Comment: @Godisgood Thanks for suggestion, I have added some description see it :)

Comment: Keep narrating, this is getting better . . .

Comment: Could you pull out the specific CSS rule(s) you changed so you could highlight where in that long snippet of CSS you made changes?  That'd be helpful I think.

Comment: @calvin I have added a transition delay property to div>span and its value is 0s;

Comment: @Muhammad Thank you.  What I meant, though, was that your answer would be more helpful for others later if you stated that more clearly (like with `<pre>`s and such) in your answer.  Good job with it, though.

Comment: @calvin Thanks for your suggestion, Now I have added a note to my answer which makes it clear :)